# Unity2d game shooting and animation sync issue

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I'm a new in Unity and making my first 2D game. I seen several topics on this forum in this issue, but I didn't found the solution.

So I have a lovely shooting animation and the bullet generation. My problem, I have to generate the bullet somewhere at the middle of the animation, but the character shoots the bullet and the animation at the same time, which killing the UX :)

I attached an image, about the issue, this is the moment, when the bullet should be initialized, but as you can see it's already on it's way.

Please find my code:
The GameManager update method calls the attackEnemy function:

```
    public void Awake(){    
        animator = GetComponent ();
        animator.SetTrigger ("enemyIdle");
    }



    //if the enemy pass this point, they stop shooting, and just go off the scren
    private float shootingStopLimit = -6f;

    public  override void  attackPlayer(){
        //animator.SetTrigger ("enemyIdle");
        if (!isAttacking && gameObject.transform.position.y > shootingStopLimit) {
            isAttacking = true;
            animator.SetTrigger("enemyShoot");
            StartCoroutine(doWait());
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren ().fireBullet ();
            StartCoroutine (Reload ());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator doWait(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    }

    private IEnumerator Reload(){
        animator.SetTrigger ("enemyIdle");

        int reloadTime = Random.Range (4,7);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);

        isAttacking = false;
    }......
```

My questions:
 - How can I sync the animation and the bullet generation ?

- Why not the doWait() works ? :)
- Is it okay to call the attackPlayer method from the GameManager update ?
- The enemies are flynig from the right side of the screen to the left, when they reach the most right side of the screen, they became visible to the user. I don't know why, but they to a shooting animation (no bullet generation happen )first, only after it they do the idle. Any idea why ?

Thanks,
K

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking out animation events. Using animation events, you can call a method to instantiate your bullet.

To use Mecanim Animation Events you need to write the name of the function you want to call at the selected frame in the "Function" area of the "Edit Animation Event" window.

The other boxes are for any variables that you want to pass to that function to trigger whatever you have in mind.

Triggering/blending between different animations can be done in many different ways. The event area is more for other things that you want to trigger that are not related to animation (e.g. audio, particle fx, etc).